# Homeomorpic spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

We define the two following sets:

$ E_1 =\{ (L,v) \in \mathbb{R}P \times \mathbb{R}^{1} \mid  v  \in  L \ or \ v=0\}  $

and

$A=([0,1] \times \mathbb{R})/\sim $    . Where $\sim$ is the equivalence defined by $(0,t) \sim  (1,-t)$

I need to show that these to set is homeomorphic.
First I noticed that $A$ is homeomorphic to the open möbius band, but I cant really go on from here.    Thanks

Comment: Just a remark: if $[L]\in\mathbb{R}P^n$ then $L$ is a line passing throught the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Hence $0\in L$ and $E_1$ is the tautological vector bundle to  $\mathbb{R}P^n$.

Comment: I think you mean $E_1 = \{(L, v) \in \mathbb{RP}^1\times\mathbb{R}^2 \mid v \in L\}$.

Answer (score 0):

These are clearly not homeomorphic as you wrote them. For one thing, the first space $E_1$ is a differential variety of dimension $n+1$ while the second one has dimension $2$. As Michael Albanese remarked, this means that you should really set $n=1$ in your first space.

Now the projective line $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)$ is a very simple beast since it is homeomorphic to the circle. This means that $E_1$ is naturally a line bundle over the circle $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)$, with the map $(L,v) \mapsto L$. An idea could be to see $A$ as another line bundle over the circle, for example by $(t, x) \mapsto t$ (which is compatible to the equivalence relation).

Now if you know enough about line bundles, it should be easy to see that $E_1$ and $A$ are isomorphic as line bundles over the circle, but we may also write an elementary proof. Namely, to an element $(t, r)$ of $A$ we associate the point $(\cos \pi t, \sin \pi t)$ of the circle (more precisely: the quotient of the circle by the half-turn map, which is a nice model of the projective line), and the line $L \subset \mathbb R^2$ with equation $L(t): x \sin \pi t - y \cos \pi t = 0$. This suggests mapping $(t, z)$ to the pair $(L(t), v(t) = (r \cos \pi t, r \sin \pi t))$ of $E_1$ (where we check that $v(t) \in L(t)$ as required). Proving that this is indeed an homeomorphism should be easy (just show the inverse map).

Note that there is nothing special about the map $t \mapsto (\cos \pi t, \sin \pi t)$, any homeomorphism between $[0,1]/\sim$ and $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)$ would have worked. This one is just a bit easier to write.

Comment: ty. I did write the sets wrong. as already mentioned at $E_1$ n should be replaced with 1. The other space should be $([0,1]\times \mathbb{R})/\sim$ with relation as before

Comment: Yup, I did only expand a bit on why the problem as asked was wrong and how we could guess how to fix it.